# Explore object's members like in debug but without debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins

Is there any extension for visual studio that can display object's properties / members / methods without debugging the code?

Like it shows in debug when you hover over an object it shows a menu where you can easily navigate between object's members.

I'm looking for extension that can do the same without debug.

If its important the language that I'm working with is C#

Comment: What do you mean by "without debug"? During development you have Intellisense for that..

Comment: Intellisense shows the public members of an object, to see another member object I need to return to the root object and show another member. Doing this closes the first member's list. What I want is a tool that will show all members/methods (public and private). And a way that I can expend a list of members and keep it expended while also seeing other members

Comment: You have Object Browser and Class View in Visual Studio - but still not sure if I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but you might find the relatively new "**peek definitions**" in visual studio helpful:

Place the caret / focus on some variable or object, and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.

That will open a sort of internal *mini window* in VS, showing the contents of the variable.

You can repeat this to step further down in thorough the internals of whatever object you are exploring. Dots at the top of the window show how many levels down you've navigated, and you can click them to move between levels.

In this example I'm at the third level down, as indicated by the blue dot:

[image]

This is a great feature for exploring the internals of your class hierarchies without actually opening a bunch of files and cluttering up your main VS window.